# php - xml - random filter and store the order

Tags: php, xml

PHP: I get XML feed of 20 articles, I have pick 3 articles randomly and print xml out in the same format. Randomly picked article should change random every day not on every refresh.

so for ex: art1, art2, art3,art......art20
it should display: art4, art2, art 19 (random) but it should with the same article for the entire day - (10/12/12) and tomorrow it should be art1,art20,art13 (another random set)

```
<?php
// Load our XML document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('feed.xml');

// Create an XPath object and register our namespaces so we can
// find the nodes that we want    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('p', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');

// Random generated xml should go here

// Write our updated XML back to a new file
$doc->save('feedout.xml');

?>
```

Since storing the article order needs server file storage, I can push that back. How can I randomize the article

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->3; $i++) {
$node = $nodes->item($i);}
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of persistent storage do you have? Database? Files? APC? You need to keep track what random articles were chosen once a day. And ... is this per client or a server-wide thing?

Answer (score 1):

How about just save your file with a date name and then check that date doesn't already exist

```
// Write our updated XML back to a new file
        if( !file_exists( $date . '_feedout.xml' ) )
            $doc->save( $date . '_feedout.xml' );
```

Or

```
 // Write our updated XML back to a new file
            if( date( "Y/m/d", filemtime( 'feedout.xml' ) ) != $date )
                $doc->save( 'feedout.xml' );
```

Comment: if it is that complicated, just help me understand how i can random generate 3 article out of 20 article for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->3; $i++) {
    $node = $nodes->item($i);}