# php - xml - randomly pick 3 sets out of 20 or length of sets

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php - xml - random filter and store the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865906/php-xml-random-filter-and-store-the-order)

Need to pick 3 xml sets from a feed (randomize).I have provided the XML format as well(for one item).It will be set of 20 or more set of items in the XML. I have to randomly pick 3 items sets out of that and publish in the same xml format.

```
<?php
// Load our XML document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('feed.xml');

// Create an XPath object and register our namespaces so we can
// find the nodes that we want    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('p', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
```

Random 3 articles insert back here.

```
// Write our updated XML back to a new file
$doc->save('feedout.xml');

?>
```

XML FORMAT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <channel>
    <title>title</title>
    <link>http://li.com</link>
    <description>li.com</description>
    <image>
      <url>http://www.li.com/feedlogo.gif</url>
      <title>link.com</title>
      <link>http://link.com</link>
    </image>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <copyright>C/copyright>
    <generator>G</generator>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
      <link><![CDATA[http://li.com/]]></link>
      <guid isPermaLink="true"><![CDATA[http://li.com/]]></guid>
      <description><![CDATA[ Desc]]></description>
      <dc:creator><![CDATA[be]]></dc:creator>
      <pubDate>Mon EST</pubDate>
      <dc:identifier>12</dc:identifier>
      <category domain="category"><![CDATA[cat]]></category>
      <category domain="blogger:name"><![CDATA[cat]]></category>
      <enclosure url="pic" length="" type="image/jpeg"/>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Can we have a copy of the XML you are working with .. you can add it to pastbin

Comment: Yes, Same person...trying in many ways...Still no answer